# Using Moq for Generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, mocking, moq

Totally simple situation, but I can't make it work.  I am running into an issue with using Moq to mock a generic method (in this case, on a Ninject Kernel interface):

```
T Get<T>();
```

I set up my mock object:

```
Mock<IKernel> mockKernel = new Mock<IKernel>();
        mockKernel.Setup(x => x.Get<IGetUserQuery>()).Returns(new GetUserQuery());
```

At runtime I get the following exception:

```
Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.Get<IGetUserQuery>(new[] {  })
```

Any idea why it's throwing this?  I've mocked generics in Moq before without a problem...  are there cases in which generic mocking isn't supported?  This seems like a straightforward case.  The only wrinkle is that IGetUserQuery in turn inherits from a genericized type:

```
IGetUserQuery : ICommand<UserQueryInput, UserQueryOutput>
```

I don't see this creating a problem because the generic types for this implementation of ICommand are staticly defined by IGetUserQuery, so I doubt this is confusing Moq.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `T Get<T> ()` isn't actually a method defined in the IKernel interface, it is an extension method defined [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Syntax/ResolutionExtensions.cs).

Why are you trying to mock `T Get<T> ()` in the first place? Interaction with the IoC container should be absolutely minimal, usually just at the toplevel "entry point" to your system.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the behavior.  Completely agree with you about directly accessing the kernel -- we are messing around with accessing the it directly at runtime in the odd case where we instantiate RequestScope objects on a SingletonScope object.